# Use Triangle Inequality and The Fact That 0<|a|<|b| ,i.e. 1/|b|<1/|a| to establish the following chain of inequalities:

Tags: calculus

The problem is from Calculus 6th Edition by Dale Varberg, page 21, problem number 34. With triangle inequality, I can easily show the first half of the inequality is valid. But I am stuck with the second half. Any help will be appreciated. |1/(x^2+3) -1/(|x|+2)|<= 1/(x^2+3) +1/(|x| +2)<=( 1/3+1/2)

Comment: Sorry guys. As soon as I finished posting, the solution just popped in my head. I guess I needed the online "therapy" session to straighten out the tiny clog in my neural pathways.:-):-) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$|A+B|\le |A|+|B|$$

$$A\ge B>0\implies 1/A \le1/B $$
$$x^2+3\ge 3>0\implies ...$$
$$|x|+2\ge 2>0\implies ...$$